# How to pass values from service to ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, service, xamarin.forms

I created service to get data from JSON file and now I'm trying to show them on page.

In service, variable `model` get correct values, but in ViewModel varibales as StationId, StationName, Message, DateText etc are null, so obvious nothing is showing on page.
(Currently I set some hardcoded values for test purpose)

Model

```
public class IrrigNetModel
    {
        public IrrigNetModelItem[] items { get; set; }
    }

    public class IrrigNetModelItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string DateText { get; set; }
        public int StationId { get; set; }
        public string StationName { get; set; }
        public float StationLongitude { get; set; }
        public float StationLatitude { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    }
```

Service

```
class IrrigNetService
    {

        public static async Task<IrrigNetModel> GetServices(string token, string lngCode)
        {
            IrrigNetModel model = new IrrigNetModel();
            try
            {
                string URL = DataURL.BASE_URL + "agronetmobile/getlistnotifications?lngCode=" + lngCode;
                string content = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", token);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Culture", LocalData.Lang);

                    HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(URL, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));                    
                    if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {

                        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        model = (IrrigNetModel)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultContent, typeof(IrrigNetModel));

                    }
                    else if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                model = null;
            }
            return model;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<IrrigNetModelItem> IrrigNetCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IrrigNetModelItem>
       {
           new IrrigNetModelItem
           {
               StationId = 1,
               StationName = "Krakatosia",
               Message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur scelerisque a lorem sit amet mattis.",
               DateText = "21.07.2012."
           }
       };

       public IrrigNetViewModel()
       {
           var token = LocalData.Token;
           IrrigNetService.GetServices(token,"sr");

           TabTappedCommand = new Command((tabName) => OnTapClicked(tabName.ToString()));
           HideListOnTapCommand = new Command(HideListOnTap);
           IrrigNetModelItem model = new IrrigNetModelItem();
           var irrigNetModel = new IrrigNetModelItem
           {
               StationId = model.StationId,
               StationName = model.StationName,
               Message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur scelerisque a lorem sit amet mattis.",
               DateText = model.DateText
           };
           IrrigNetCollection.Add(irrigNetModel);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the service but not storing the result

```
IrrigNetService.GetServices(token,"sr");
```

instead, try this

```
var data = await IrrigNetService.GetServices(token,"sr");

foreach (var d in data.items) {
  IrrigNetCollection.Add(d);
}
```

Comment: I tryed this, but then I got net error: `The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.`
After that I tryed to remove 'avait' from your solution, and then I get: `Task<IrrigNetModel>' does not contain a definition for 'items' and no accessible extension method 'items' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IrrigNetModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: please take the time to read the C# docs on using async.  There are numerous questions on SO that discuss calling async methods from the constructor.

Comment: Thanks I will, ofcourse. But is there any hint for this certain problem now?

Comment: I would suggest to not load the data in the ViewModel constructor. Create a separate method in your VM, that is **async**, to load the data and then call that method when the `OnAppearing` is fired in your page.